# "Unsupported compression method 98" error when unzipping a file. What tools support it, other than WinZip?

Tags: windows, compression, zip, archiving, winzip

I'm getting an error message: `"unsupported compression method 98"` when unzipping a file somebody sent to me.  I've tried both an older version of [WinZip](http://www.winzip.com/index.htm), and [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) 4.65.

(*Update:* I've also tried Windows own built-in Compressed Folders to open the archive (on Windows 7), but it reports `Unspecified Error 0x80004005` on the archive.  Presumably, that means Windows itself doesn't support this compression method, either.)

I've already asked the person to avoid using a non-standard compression method and re-send the file.  I know WinZip (of which they are using a newer version) has compatibility options.  But, I'm wondering:

**What archiving utilities, *other than WinZip*, support this "compression method 98"?**

In particular, is there a free and/or open source tool that supports that method?  If not, why not?  Is the method strictly proprietary to WinZip?

Comment: see http://www.winzip.com/comp_info.htm

Comment: @user12889: Thanks.  Yes, it's "PPMd" that I'm referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [7zip 9.14](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/). 7zip beta's are like other software in stable, so don't worry.

Comment: **Confirmed: 7-Zip 9.14 can unarchive compression method 98 (PPMd) ZIP archives. Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

one of those

http://www.macwindows.com/compress.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_archivers

I Highlight PKZIP and UHARC

**:**)

Comment: Thanks, but do you have knowledge that those tools specifically support "compression method 98", also known as **PPMd** ?  I'm not looking for simply *any* alternative to WinZip, but **one that specifically supports "compression method 98".**